# Is it valid to split an API in different microservices?

Tags: architecture, microservices, services

Taking the following scenario.

A blog where anyone can see publications and comments and users with enough privileges who create, update or delete this publications or comments.

- **Publication list service** (M1) is in charge to **only** list publications and comments.
- **Publication service** (M2) which basically save, update or delete.

At first I thought **Publication service** (M3) could do everything (CRUD) but let's say publication form is somehow complex and depends on others services, if I decide to shutdown M3 for a maintenance

- How can I still show to users the list of publications?
- Is it right to separate an API for these scenarios?
- Am I missing a service or software who can solve this?

PS: While writing I remembered about CI/CD but again if I want users to only see publications and comments and not publish any until the service is up. How can I handle this?

Comment: I've read your question several times, but I still don't understand what you're asking.  If this is about redundancy, there are more or less standard ways to get that.

Comment: Yes it is about redundancy in a way. Do you about any those standard ways you mention about can help in this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

I would advise against this. One of the core principles of microservices is that a service should own its data. If data is shared, services tend not to be independently deployable due to coupling with the data. ie - what happens when you need to version your data model? The write api needs to know about and the read api needs to know about it and you can’t deploy them at the same time...

I’d just make them their own api together and be done with it. You don’t gain much from keeping them separate in most scenarios.

Comment: One of my concerns was about shared data. Now is clear. But then how can I make possible to show a list even when service in charge is off?

Comment: Could always do the old Blue Green deployment with a load balancer trick.

Comment: Telastyn is right. Microservice no matter how micro they are, they still respond to the principle of cohesion. Just go through the way that allow you to disable/enable certain parts of the interface (API). For instance via gateways in front of the API or API management systems. Breaking a service by its CRUD will increase significatively the service complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at CQRS Command Query Response Segregation and Event Sourcing.

Under this your publisher could just publish events when an article is published and the query store could for example just write it to disk or a lucene index or something optimised for reads. So in effect you'd have a flat site for consumers and maybe a SQL store only on the publisher side.